# Исправить несбалансированные скобки в строке

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли библиотека, которая автоматически исправит несбалансированные скобки в строке? Могут быть только незакрытые скобки, неоткрытых не может быть. Везде берём максимальное количество символов в скобки.

```
'xxx (yyy (zzz)' -> 'xxx (yyy (zzz))'
'x(x()v' -> 'x(x()v)'
```

Comment: Нет. Потому что в общем случае правильных вариантов много. Например почему не `x(x())v` во втором примере?

Comment: `xxx (yyy (zzz) -> xxx (yyy) (zzz)` не так уж оно однозначно

Comment: @AlexeyTen@vp_arth везде по максимуму символов в скобках

Comment: Это легко сделать если вам не важно в каком месте поставить недостающие скобки - просто считаете и ставите вначале недостающие открывающиеся или вконец закрывающиеся скобки. :)

Comment: @MaxU неоткрытых скобок не может быть, только незакрытые. А ставить надо не где угодно, а по максимум символов в скобках, т.е. во втором примере не может быть `x(x)()v`, единственно верный вариант `x(x()v)`

Comment: @MaxU по такому условию - да, всегда в конце надо ставить. Но надо знать сколько именно ставить

Comment: Не можете посчитать число открывающих и закрывающих скобок??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'xxx (yyy (zzz)'
print(s + ")" * (s.count("(") - s.count(")")))
```